# Kali Linux 4.6.0-kali1-686-pae issues

Tags: linux-kernel, software-installation, kali-linux

I am using a virtual machine to run Kali linux and when I run this command `apt-get install -y dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)` it gives me this error:

```
E:Unable to locate package dkms
E:Unable to lcoate package linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-686-pae
E:Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-686-pae'
E:Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-686-pae'
```

The contents of the uname variable are:

```
4.6.0-kali1-686-pae
```

How can I fix this error, it is stopping me from following a tutorial. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following error `E:Unable to lcoate package linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-686-pae` mean that the package is not yet available on the active kali-linux repository.

You should upgrade your kernel version then install the apropriate `linux-headers` package

Run the following command to find out the latest `linux-image`:

```
apt update
apt-cache search linux-image
```

Sample output:

```
linux-image-4.9.0-kali3-686-pae
linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-686-pae
```

To install it run;

```
apt install linux-image-4.9.0-kali3-686-pae
```

Reboot your system then install the `linux-headers` package:

```
apt install linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-686-pae
```